# when file name has space, how to use variable in script?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to open a application using shell script.

But! when file name has space, script read this as two files.

```
1 path=/Applications
2 program=/Google Chrome.app    
3 open $path$program
```

it's not working...

when I use alias like these...

```
program="/Google Chrome.app" or
program=/Google\ Chrome.app  or
program="/Google\ Chrome.app"
```

shell cognized two files like this

```
"The files /Applications/Google and /current_dir/Chrome.app do not exist."
```

How I fix that?
please give me your teaching

Comment: `open "$path/$program"`

Comment: See ["When should I wrap quotes around a shell variable?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-should-i-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) (short answer: almost always).

Comment: You have tagged the question by _bash_  or by _zsh_ . Which shell are you interested in? If you need to know this for both shells, ask two questions (because bash and zsh are a bit different in this respect.

Comment: _when I use alias like these_  : There is no alias in the code you provided. `program` is a _shell variable_.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your variables in quotes. So what you can do is:

```sh
path=Applications
program="Google Chrome.app"
open /$path/$program
```